# How to calculate the time needed for objects to grow in size in the viewing field when approaching them?

Tags: geometry

I would like to calculate how much time does a 5 m tall house, a 300 m tall skyscraper and an 8000 m tall mountain - each need to grow in size in the viewing field - from the size of a pebble with 1 mm in diameter, to the size of a coin with 1 cm diameter, to the size of a coin with 3 cm diameter,  to the size of a dish plate with 20 cm diameter, with each obscuring object (pebble, coin,...) held up at 20 cm from the face?

(I realize the obscuring objects are of different shapes than main objects, so speaking only it terms of edges of the main objects fitting exactly behind the diameter of the obscuring objects when they are held at 20 cm from the face.)

What is the basic equation? We have sizes of the objects we are approaching, sizes of the obscuring objects and speed by which we are approaching the objects. If other information is required for the equation, please feel free to make up amounts for the sake of the example...

I would than like to apply different speeds of 5 mph, 10 mph and 35 mph with all other information staying the same.

Is the rate at which the object gets bigger constant?? (I have a strong intuitive feeling that the closer you get to the object, the faster it grows, but I'm pretty sure that it's wrong...) In other words if I don't change the speed, will the object need the same amount of time to grow from 1 mm to 1.1 cm and from 14 cm to 15 cm in the viewing field??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The dimension of the image on a screen and the real dimension of the object are linked by a simple proportion to the respective distances, as you  can see in the figure.

[image]

If $AB=r$ and $AC=R$, the dimension of the image $k=EB$ is given by
$$
k=j\cdot \frac{r}{R}
$$
where $j=CD$ is the real dimension of the object.

If the distance $R$ change in time because $A$ is going to $C$ with a constant velocity $v$ , than $R=R_0 -vt$, where $R_0$ is the distance at the time $t=0$, and the apprent dimension on the screen change as 
$$
k=j\cdot \frac{r}{R_0 -vt}
$$

Note that in this equation, for physical constrains, we must have $ R_0 -vt>r$

Using this approach you can solve all your problems.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful hints. I am applying some numbers and the results seem reasonable. However for now, I am only using the first equation you wrote and extracting the differences. I will post a follow up comment with results I get...